# How to use if-else with string in angular2 expression

Tags: angular, if-statement, angular2-template, ngfor

I wanna to generate html code like below by `*ngFor` into angular 2 expression.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

I use this code but it's not true:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li *ngFor="let item of siteMap; let isLast = last" [class.active]="isLast">
        {{isLast == true ? item : "<a href='#'>"+ item +"</a>"}}
    </li>
</ol>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li *ngFor="let item of siteMap; let isLast = last">
    <a *ngIf="!isLast" href="#">{{item}}</a>
    {{isLast ? item: ''}}
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li *ngFor="let item of siteMap; let isLast = last">
     <a *ngIf="!isLast; else notLast" href="#">{{item}}</a>
     <ng-template #notLast>{{isLast ? item: ''}}</ng-template>  </li>
</ol>.
```

Using *ngIf and *ngFor on the same element will throw an error.